# Scala Spark Job in Dataproc cluster returns java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I get the error

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
```

when I run my Job using a Dataproc cluster, when I run it locally it runs perfectly. I have recreated the issue using the following toy example.

```
package com.deequ_unit_tests

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object reduce_by_key_example {def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  // Set the log level to only print errors
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()

  println("Step 1")
  val data = Seq(("Project", 1),
    ("Gutenberg’s", 1),
    ("Alice’s", 1),
    ("Adventures", 1),
    ("in", 1),
    ("Wonderland", 1),
    ("Project", 1),
    ("Gutenberg’s", 1),
    ("Adventures", 1),
    ("in", 1),
    ("Wonderland", 1),
    ("Project", 1),
    ("Gutenberg’s", 1))

  println("Step 2")
  val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

  println("Step 3")
  val rdd2 = rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)

  println("Step 4")
  rdd2.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

When I run this job in Dataproc, I get this error when executing the line

```
rdd2.foreach(println)
```

As additional information, I have to say that I wasn't receiving this error until some changes where applied in my company's Dataproc cluster. For colleagues using PySpark, with an equivalent version in Pyspark of the example above, changing

```
  sc = SparkContext('local')
```

to

```
  sc = SparkContext()
```

did the trick, but I couldn't find an equivalent solution in Spark Scala. Do you have any idea about what could be causing this issue? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Don’t set master while creating the spark session , SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()

Comment: It works for the toy example (but not printing when rdd2.foreach(println)). Nevertheless not adding master in the real case I am working in, makes the process return this error before it would break with .master added:

WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, dataproc-managed-w-91.c.wf-gcp-us-ae-dataproc-prod.internal, executor 2): java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2964184825620630609, local class serialVersionUID = -3988734315685039601

Comment: By the way you can not print row of rdd without making transformations ( immutability of an rdd) , just check the different versions compatibly, I have also a question are you running this code from zeppelin notebook on VM dataproc or using a jar ?

Comment: The toy example is taken from here https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-spark-rdd/spark-reducebykey-usage-with-examples/. Is anything missing? It runs perfectly locally and prints the desired output.

Anyway, this example only serves to illustrate the issue I am facing.

Comment: well i don't understand what you mean by local (in your machine ) well in dataproc , would you share your code please !

Comment: Could you share what kind of changes were applied to your company's cluster? Are you creating a new cluster every time you run this job or are you using a pre-existing one? What is the image-version of your cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Configure your pom.xml or your build.sbt as follow:

Add the  provided  scope in the script :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>stackOverFlowGcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>


        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- assembly Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>mainPackage.mainObject</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

2. Create your package : Clean => rebuild => compile => package

```
package mainPackage
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object mainObject {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      //.master("local[*]")
      .appName("SparkByExamples")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    println("Step 1")
    val data = Seq(("Project", 1),
      ("Gutenberg’s", 1),
      ("Alice’s", 1),
      ("Adventures", 1),
      ("in", 1),
      ("Wonderland", 1),
      ("Project", 1),
      ("Gutenberg’s", 1),
      ("Adventures", 1),
      ("in", 1),
      ("Wonderland", 1),
      ("Project", 1),
      ("Gutenberg’s", 1))

    println("Step 2")
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
    println("Step 3")
    val rdd2 = rdd.reduceByKey(_ + _)

    println("Step 4")
    rdd2.foreach(println)


  }
}
```

3. Create your dataproc Cluster
4. Run the spark job in dataproc

In dataproc you will not see the result as a mentionned before, if you want to know just read more about Dataproc approch on that. However you can show a dataframe in dataproc if you like.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see in dataproc every thing is working fine.
Don't forget to shut down the cluster or delete it after finishing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the following log:

```
ERROR Executor:94 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:529)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:527)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.getShuffleEndpointClient(SparkEnv.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommitRemote(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.IndexShuffleBlockResolver.writeIndexFileAndCommit(IndexShuffleBlockResolver.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.io.LocalDiskShuffleMapOutputWriter.commitAllPartitions(LocalDiskShuffleMapOutputWriter.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.writePartitionedData(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:224)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:505)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:508)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I solved this by setting the master to **yarn**. In fact, I was deploying the spark in **client** mode to a Dataproc cluster (gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark)

```scala
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("yarn")
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()
```